# numpy.concatencate two same size row vector to matrix

Tags: python, numpy

```
a=np.random.uniform(0,1,10)
b=np.random.uniform(0,1,10)
a=np.concatenate(a,b, axis=0)
```

I am refresh `a` to be `(2x10)` matrix. But what I got was just an `(1x20)` array.

The example works well.

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = np.array([[5, 6]])
np.concatenate((a, b), axis=0)
```

gives

```
array([[1, 2],
   [3, 4],
   [5, 6]])
```

Why? And what can I do to change this?

Thank you and the editor.

Comment: Well, in the working example all is already 2D, while you start 1D, i.e. all entries are on axis 0. Hence, numpy does what you ask for.

Comment: I think what you're looking for here is `numpy.array([a,b])`

Comment: try `np.random.uniform(0,1,10).reshape(1,10)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to solve this (I'm sure there are many alternatives) is to create `a` and `b` as 2-dimensional arrays, with dimensions 1x10, rather than simply making them 1-dimensional arrays. You can do this by passing a tuple as the `size` argument to `np.random.uniform`:

```
a = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (1, 10))
b = np.random.uniform(0, 1, (1, 10))
result = np.concatenate((a, b), axis=0)
```